# Does R use 0-indexing for dates?

Tags: r, indexing

R uses the date `"1970-01-01"` as an origin. Does it make an exception from its typical 1-indexing to index dates with 0-indexing?

```
> x <- as.Date("1970-01-01")
> y <- as.Date("1970-01-02")

> unclass(x)
[1] 0

> unclass(y)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Those are not indices. They are the number of completed days since the origin. You will also see zero as the starting point for several other datetime classes of values. It is I believe a POSIX-mandated thing.

Comment: Thank you both for clearing up the difference between an origin/sentinel value and an index. I'm happy to accept an answer if you'd like to drop it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is not an indexing thing. "Dates are represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01" (From the `?Date` help page). Also note

```
unclass(as.Date("1969-12-31")) == -1
```

So it's not an index, it's a difference from a sentinel value. There's no underlying vector here.